# JQuery DatePicker Multiple Input

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

Using JQuery And ASP.Net C#3.0.

I have the following Script:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $("[id$=txtHiddenDate]").datepicker({
          showOn: "button",
          buttonImage: "../../images/calendar-icon.gif",
          buttonImageOnly: true
      });
  });
</script>
```

There are 3 separate fields for day month and year.(txtDay, txtMonth, txtYear)
How do return the date to these 3 separate fields?

Many thanks!

EDIT: also I want to keep hidden field aswell

Comment: why would you want to have a hidden date picker? Just use a hidden text field with the date or show a date picker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML**

Setups up the other inputs to hold the pieces of the date.  You may want to make these hidden.

```
<input id="picker"/><br>
Day:
<input id="day"/><br>
Month:
<input id="month"/><br>
Year:
<input id="year"/>
```

**Javascript**

Specifies an `onSelect` function that parses the different pieces of the date and assigns them to respective inputs.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#picker").datepicker({
          showOn: "button",
          buttonImage: "../../images/calendar-icon.gif",
          buttonImageOnly: true,
          onSelect: function(strDate){
             var tokens = strDate.split("/");
              $("#day").val(tokens[1]);
              $("#month").val(tokens[0]);
              $("#year").val(tokens[2]);

          }
      });
  });
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/9Ww8g/

Comment: perfect answer, I was about to start using the code behind C# (yup I try not to touch JQuery as It is not my area) nice a and simple!

Answer (score 0):

You should apply the datepicker on a normal textbox. You can't have it on a hidden field or three different fields.

Because it's a textbox, on the server-side (in your code-behind) you'll only have a string. Use `[DateTime.Parse][1]`, `[DateTime.TryParse][2]`, `[DateTime.ParseExact][3]` or to get the selected date.

If you want to work with the `hiddenField` and have it in a certain format (so you can parse knowing the format), you can use `altField` and `altFormat`:

```
$("#myTextBox").datepicker({ 
    altField: "#myHiddenField",
    altFormat: "yy-mm-dd" 
});
```

If it's an ASP.NET hiddenfield, you might want to use the following selector:

```
altField: "input[id$=myHiddenField]"
```

because in your javascript, you can't know the actual id ASP.NET will generate (unless you construct your javascript in code-behind).